# NSURLSession crash

Tags: crash, nsurlsession, cfnetwork

Just on one client device iPhone4s with iOS7.1 we have crash with stack:

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.NSURLSession-work
0  CoreFoundation                 0x2d6419be CFURLCopyScheme + 49
1  CFNetwork                      0x2d30b67d _urlIsHTTPish + 8
2  CFNetwork                      0x2d30b67d _urlIsHTTPish + 8
3  CFNetwork                      0x2d31f725 URLRequest::addOverridingSessionAttributes(_CFURLSessionConfiguration*) + 216
4  CFNetwork                      0x2d374eb9 ClassicConnectionSession::createConnectionWithProperties(_CFURLRequest const*, __CFDictionary const*) const + 552
5  CFNetwork                      0x2d35697d __73-[__NSCFLocalSessionBridge downloadTaskForRequest:resumeData:completion:]_block_invoke + 196
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x3844081f _dispatch_client_callout + 22
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x384467cb _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 26
8  CFNetwork                      0x2d2fbd89 -[__NSCFLocalSessionTask resume] + 100
```

Does anybody else had this?

**EDIT**:
Duplication of question: [Asynchronous downloading in UICollectionView error with AFNetworking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25266727/2035054)

CFURLCopyScheme crashed as CFURL passed to this method is nil, iOS7 does not check if url passed to NSURLSessionDownloadTask is valid.

Check that:

1) NSURL passed to request downloadTaskWithRequest was not nil

2) NSURL does not contain invalid characters e.g:

```
% |{}><"\`
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I had a http proxy active (Charles with ssl) after trying to follow a redirect. The reason was an invalid redirect url in the 302 response.